# Metric system on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When clicking the 'Location' field on the careers site, I can choose a distance… in miles…

Most people on this planet don't really know what a mile is and if they are like me, they don't really care :-/

So I suggest you add the option to use the [metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system), or if the option already exists, to make it (much) more visible, because I couldn't locate it.

Just to let you know that this could be a big deal, let me show you a map of countries using the metric system (Hint: it isn't the red ones O.o):

[image]

Anyhow, I know Liberia, Burma and such are important markets for Stack Exchange, but the rest of the world uses this site as well ;-)

Comment: Mandatory The Oatmeal: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/senior_year

Comment: This is deceptive: England uses miles.

Comment: This map is more accurate http://cdn3.chartsbin.com/chartimages/l_5261_f7c5398f20d86fd0ccf06bc70ef88c55 ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill I see no yellow. Ireland would have been yellow not long ago.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen Not long ago? Distance signposts in Northern Ireland show distances in miles, while all signposts placed in the Republic since the 1990s use kilometres.

Comment: @DavidPostill As I said, yellow: Distances in km, but speed limits in mph. We had that here in Ireland not long ago. We have now switched to km/h.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen OK. So it was yellow but green now? Isn't that what the map shows? I don't understand your point. That is not meant to be a historical map.

Comment: @DavidPostill My point is that it has yellow in the key, though it appears nowhere on the map. Which is odd. That's all. Remarks about Ireland were incidental, but may explain why the yellow key exists.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen Ah OK. Got it.

Comment: Never mind distance in miles; why is it that 99.9% of Americans assume the whole world uses their whacky mm-dd-yyyy date format (when actually *only* they do)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We actually do have kilometers as part of our localization system, but there seem to be a couple bugs in here.  We'll look into it.

Also, the first time we did this, we flipped Northern Ireland and the UK over to kilometers.  We won't make that mistake again.

**UPDATE**

Took a bit longer that we had expected.  This was like bug inception, but it should all be fixed now.  The localization choices between km and miles is determined by your location, not language preferences or whether you are on .com or .com/de or .com/fr

Comment: Er.. Northern Ireland is part of the UK.

Comment: @Chenmunka Yes of course.  I won't edit out my mistake.  I should be shamed.  I've only watched this 5 times: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNu8XDBSn10

Answer (score 7):

It could be as simple as this (adjusting the CSS-ishies, of course):

[image]

Comment: This could work rather nicely - a constructive compromise!

Comment: 20 miles = 32.1869 Km ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill In that case: _"19.8839 miles/32 Km"_ :-)

Comment: The fix we're actually putting in (although this was cool) is simply based off your location which determines km or miles preference.  In our localization system right now, that is tied to language preference, which is wrong.  It will behave much more like our currencies for employers, which are not tied to languages but rather locations.